# How to insert a datetime in specific format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to insert a `currentdatetime` in these format `YYYYMMDD:HHMMSSS`
Which query should i write?

Comment: what type of column you have ?

Comment: Don't insert a date as a string. Store it as a `Date`, that way people can easily format it however they want down the line (without having to parse a string first).

Comment: Nvarchar(255)




Nvarchar(255) is the cloumn type

Comment: @TirthaRoyChowdhury - if you are using sql sever then you should write query as given in answer

Comment: Thanks Pranay for the query☺

Comment: welcome ..you can upvote too if worked for you

Comment: Storing the date as string ((n)varchar) will give all sorts of issues when you want to use it as date. So please store a date as such and let display code worry about formatting

Comment: Hi pranay,the query is giving result in the format HHMMSS but i want in HHMMSSS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL server you can do like this, and your type should be `Varchar`

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) + ':' + 
       REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 108), ':', '')
```

result

```
20180425:064801
```